# SQL - How to insert multiple records as one record without pivot?

Tags: sql-server

i want to create a query from multiple records as one record , but i don't want to use Pivot, is there any solutions?

here's the table :

```
ID   Element_Name  Value
1    Parmitha      100
2    Anggun        200
3    Chandra       300
4    BagusofTerror 400
```

and i want the result is like this :

```
paramitha , anggun, chandra , bagusofterror
100 , 200, 300, 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for xml path ('')` to transpose the values of a column.

For example, you could write

```
select Element_Name + ', '
from TheTable
for xml path ('');
```

To get `Parmitha, Anggun, Chandra, BagusofTerror,`

Here's a live demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71f88/24

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Select 
    MAX(CASE WHEN colID = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Parmitha],
    MAX(CASE WHEN colID = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Anggun],
    MAX(CASE WHEN colID = 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Chandra],
    MAX(CASE WHEN colID = 4 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [BagusofTerror]

FROM    
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS colID,
            ID,
            Element_Name,
            value
        FROM    Sample
    ) AS d
```

[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b596e/12)

Taking Wolf's answer into consideration ,using dynamic query and xml path

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                    + convert(varchar(max), Element_Name, 120)
                from Sample
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select  value, Element_Name
            from Sample
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(value)
            for Element_Name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

 execute(@query);
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b596e/30)

By the way y don't u use `PIVOT` .Using PIVOT the same result can be achieved

```
 Select [Parmitha],[Anggun],[Chandra],[BagusofTerror] 
 FROM 
 (
  Select value,element_name from Sample
 )src
 pivot
 (
  max(value)
  for Element_Name in ([Parmitha],[Anggun],[Chandra],[BagusofTerror])
 )pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use COALESCE to pivot a results set of columns into a varchar variable:

```
CREATE TABLE #Pivot
(ID int, Element_Name varchar(50), Value int)

INSERT #Pivot values (1,'Parmitha',100)
INSERT #Pivot values (2,'Anggun',200)
INSERT #Pivot values (3,'Chandra',300)
INSERT #Pivot values (4,'BagusofTerror',400)

DECLARE @titles VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @values VARCHAR(1000)
SET @titles = ''
SET @values = ''

SELECT @titles = @titles + COALESCE(Element_Name + ',' , '')
FROM #Pivot ORDER BY ID

SELECT @values = @values + COALESCE(convert(varchar, Value) + ',' , '')
FROM #Pivot ORDER BY ID

SELECT @titles
UNION ALL
SELECT @values
```

Gives:

Parmitha,Anggun,Chandra,BagusofTerror,

100,200,300,400,